# How to solve this equation without using "observation"

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am learning Further Mathematics (British curriculum) and I've come across a problem which I need some help with, if possible.

$$4\sin(4a) + 20a = 5\pi$$

The mark scheme says by observation the answer is $a=\frac{\pi}{4}$ but is there a way to solve this without using 'observation'?

Comment: There might be a few ways involving calculus or numerical methods but I imagine that's a bit above your level.

Comment: If you could suggest the actual topic, I can take a look (much appreciated)

Comment: Can you use numerical methods? In general, such equations (transcendental equations) don't have nice solutions. For example, a very similar equation
$$ 4\sin(4a) + 19a = 5\pi$$
has the solution $a\approx 0.965818916$ which is not expressable in closed form.

Comment: Thanks guys, which numerical methods in particular? I've used iteration and Newton-Raphson in the past

Comment: Newton-Raphson should work. You're trying to find the root of the function
$$f(a) = 4\sin(4a) + 20a - 5\pi = 0 $$

Comment: Brilliant thanks @Eff

Comment: Solving $$\text{(some stuff)}+20a-5\pi=0$$ a first try would be to see what happens to (some stuff) if $20a-5\pi$ vanishes.

Answer (score 3):

$4\sin(4a) + 20a = 5\pi \implies \sin(4a) + 5a = \frac{5}{4} \pi \implies \sin(4a)=5(\frac{\pi}{4} -a)$

But we know that $-1 \le \sin x \le 1$

So $-1 \le 5(\frac{\pi}{4} -a) \le 1$ 
$$\implies \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{5} \le a \le \frac{\pi}{4}+ \frac{1}{5}$$

Now you try $a=\frac{\pi}{4}$ (because it is most probably the answer) and it works.

I know this is still kind of an "observation" but it is a much more clearer one

Comment: Thank you @Fareed AF, that does make it clearer. I was thinking that I was missing some simple algebraic solution but I'm glad that it was more difficult than I thought :)

Comment: Yes you're right it seems to be a simple problem but it is not that simple

Answer (score 1):

Hardly, because $a$ is at two different levels so to say in this equation (as $a$ and as a $\sin(a)$). No transformation would bring these two levels closer. A numerical solution using the Newton's method is usually used in such cases, when the solution is needed.

Comment: I used f(0) and after 4/5 iterations using Newton's method, the calculator came out at pi/4 :)

Comment: So one approach to disentangle the levels would be to try to make one of them zero and see whether the other level can then be solved: try to make the sin 0 and see what happens to the linear part or make the linear part 0 (as Michael Hoppe suggested in the comments) and see what happens to the sin part.